# How to access oracle PDB remotely?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, python

I have create oracle 12c instance with 2 PDBs, I am able to connect to CDB from python using cx_Oracle module but not sure how to connect to PDB.

Comment: By using their service names.

Answer (score 2):

My environment (18c XE docker):

```
sqlplus "sys/oracle@localhost:1521/XE as sysdba"
sys@XE> show pdbs

    CON_ID CON_NAME                       OPEN MODE  RESTRICTED
---------- ------------------------------ ---------- ----------
         2 PDB$SEED                       READ ONLY  NO
         3 XEPDB1                         READ WRITE NO
         4 XEPDB2                         MOUNTED
sys@XE>
```

You will find the corresponding SERVICE_NAME for PDBS by:

```
sys@XE> select service_id,name,pdb,con_id from cdb_services order by con_id;

SERVICE_ID NAME                                     PDB                      CON_ID
---------- ---------------------------------------- -------------------- ----------
         1 SYS$BACKGROUND                           CDB$ROOT                      1
         4 xe                                       CDB$ROOT                      1
         3 xeXDB                                    CDB$ROOT                      1
         2 SYS$USERS                                CDB$ROOT                      1
         8 XEPDB1                                   XEPDB1                        3

5 rows selected.
```

You may define the SERVICE_NAME the way you want for your PDB. It is a good practice to name your database service. You can also configure your database to expose multiple SERVICE_NAMEs for the same database.
For example at a TV station you have multiple channels. Their content is different so they go into separate schemas (CNN_NATIONAL, CNN_INTERNATIONAL).

```
sqlplus user/pass@something/CNN_NATIONAL
sqlplus user/pass@something/CNN_INTERNATIONAL
```

The point is you only need ONE Oracle Database to serve multiple applications separated by schemas. Now that we have containers we can have even better isolation/separation.

sys@XE> @[g](https://gist.github.com/bjarteb/26012adac01e70d1b0487d555cb74d3e) XEPDB1

```
sys:XEPDB1@XE> exec dbms_service.CREATE_SERVICE('cnn_int_prod','cnn-int-prod.cnn.com');
                                     
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.                                   
                                     
Elapsed: 00:00:00.05             
sys:XEPDB1@XE> exec dbms_service.start_service('cnn_int_prod');                                                                                        

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.                                 
                                                                           
Elapsed: 00:00:00.02                                                    

sys:XEPDB1@XE> select service_id,name,network_name,pdb,con_id from cdb_services order by con_id;

SERVICE_ID NAME                           NETWORK_NAME                   PDB                      CON_ID
---------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------ -------------------- ----------
         8 XEPDB1                         XEPDB1                         XEPDB1                        3
         1 SERVEMEWELL                    pdbprod1.us.oracle.com         XEPDB1                        3
         2 cnn_int_prod                   cnn-int-prod.cnn.com           XEPDB1                        3

3 rows selected.


sqlplus system/oracle@localhost:1521/cnn-int-prod.cnn.com

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Aug 11 15:21:12 2020
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Tue Aug 11 2020 14:58:37 +02:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.4.0.0.0

system@XEPDB1>    

Best of luck!
```

Comment: [NETWORK_NAME: Network name used to connect to the service](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-0091C6CB-6852-4253-8FE7-7F0FF053C652.htm#REFRN20465), so NETWORK_NAME should be queried from [cdb_services](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-2B8A1B8B-4F5B-4FBB-AE0B-68B6F8BA7D5E.htm#REFRN009) instead of NAME

Comment: @miracle173 Thank you, answer updated

Comment: Thanks for your response. I followed your steps and started service but it doesn't show up in listener status.

Comment: @TheBeginner Manual service registration being picked up by the listener by: SQL>alter system register; (PMON is usually responsible for this every 60s depending on your listener configuration. Static or Dynamic instance registration.

Comment: The problem is, how do you specify the service name instead of the sid in `cx_Oracle`

Comment: @Superdooperhero connection = cx_Oracle.connect("username", password, "localhost:1521/cnn-int-prod.cnn.com", encoding="UTF-8")    documentation: https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html